# MERGE to update a column of a table using Spark SQL

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, databricks, databricks-sql

Coming from MS SQL background, I'm trying to write a query in Spark SQL that simply update a column value of table A (source table) by INNER JOINing a new table B with a filter.

MS SQL query looks like this:

```
UPDATE T
SET T.OffAmount = OSE.EndAmountValue
FROM #TempOff T
INNER JOIN OffSeq OSE
    ON OSE.OffId = T.OffID
    AND OSE.OffSequenceId = 1
```

Since spark sql didn't like the UPDATE command, I've been using MERGE to update records -- as​ suggested in [this post](https://community.databricks.com/s/question/0D53f00001nXEfJCAW/does-spark-sql-can-perform-update-with-inner-join-and-like-with-column-) -- which worked fine for cases without the filter. But when there is an filter like "OSE.OffSequenceId = 1" in the spark sql query below, I'm not sure where I should add the filter (I added a WHERE clause here but not sure if that's the correct syntax):

```
%sql
MERGE into TempOff VIEW
USING OffSeq OSE ON VIEW.OffId = OSE.OffID
WHERE OSE.OffId = 1
WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE set VIEW.OffAmount = OSE.EndAmountValue;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new temp view with the updated column using left join

```
SELECT T.*
   , if(OSE.OfferEventSequenceId == 1, OSE.EndpointEventAmountValue, null) as OfferAmount
FROM TempOffer T
LEFT JOIN OfferSeq OSE
   ON T.OfferId = OSE.OfferId
```